# How to use / as sysdba in pluggable database?

Tags: oracle, expdp

I'm trying to make a export, usually I use `userid=\"/ as sysdba\"` syntax in Linux command line (I don't know sys password in my production environment.

How can I do this using pluggable database? I tried something like this: `userid=\"/ as sysdba@mypdb_oracle_net\"` but it does not work.

```
expdp userid=\"/ as sysdba@mypdb_oracle_net\" dumpfile=full_%U.exp logfile=full.log directory=teste full=y parallel=4 version=11.2.0

Export: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Mar 10 11:18:06 2020
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
UDE-00002: invalid username or password

Username:
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to export from a PDB you shouldn't use SYS for that. It is way over-privileged. You should create a user in the PDB and use that user to connect to the database. You can use the privilege "exp_full_database" to grant the necessary privileges.

Next, you have to specify a connect string to go directly into the PDB (via the relevant service). It is "mypdb_oracle_net" in your example. However, when doing so, you must specify the password for SYS. You can't use OS authentication when doing this.

To solve your problem I would do something like this:

```
SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=mypdb;
CREATE USER EXPORT_USER IDENTIFIED BY YOUR_PASSWORD;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO EXPORT_USER;
GRANT exp_full_database TO EXPORT_USER;

EXPDP EXPORT_USER/YOUR_PASSWORD@mypdb_oracle_net dumpfi......
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `\"/ as sysdba@mypdb_oracle_net\"` will not work. SYSDBA OS authentication will not work through the listener.

Second, `\"/ as sysdba\"` is flawed in 19c (compared to earlier versions), because of a bug:

[Bug 28707931 - Running IMPDP With OS Authentication Prompts For A Password (Doc ID 28707931.8)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=28707931.8)

Basically Data Pump will prompt for a password using the above, where you can enter anything and it will proceed. The bug is fixed in 20.1, or you can download a one-off patch for your version with a valid support contract.

Just create a user and use its name and password.

Answer (score 0):

There is an unpublished environment variable `ORACLE_PDB_SID`, which works in conjunction with `ORACLE_SID`.

#### Example 1

With just `ORACLE_SID` set, you will connect `CDB$ROOT`

```
export ORACLE_SID=cdb1
sqlplus / as sysdba
show con_name
```

#### Example 2

With both set, you will connect to the PDB, if it exists.

```
export ORACLE_PDB_SID=pdb2
sqlplus / as sysdba
show con_name
```

However, if cdb1 does not have pdb2, then you will be connected to `CDB$ROOT`.

When `ORACLE_PDB_SID` is set, you will NOT connect to `CDB$ROOT` if the PDB exists.

References:

Both from [Mike Dietrich](https://mikedietrichde.com/mike-dietrich-master-product-manager-database-upgrade-and-migrations-at-oracle/)'s blog:

- [Can you connect as SYSDBA without password into a PDB directly?](https://mikedietrichde.com/2020/05/07/can-you-connect-as-sysdba-without-password-into-a-pdb-directly/) (20200507)
- [Pitfalls: Connect to a PDB directly with ORACLE_PDB_SID](https://mikedietrichde.com/2020/07/13/pitfalls-connect-to-a-pdb-directly-with-oracle_pdb_sid/) (20200713)

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from Mike Dietrich's blog too

Here is a summary of the blog post

At first, I set the environment variable:

```
export ORACLE_PDB_SID=PDBHUGO
```

And then I connect with / as sysdba and see what happens.

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu May 7 22:30:05 2020
Version 19.7.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.7.0.0.0

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDBHUGO
```

https://mikedietrichde.com/2020/05/07/can-you-connect-as-sysdba-without-password-into-a-pdb-directly/